# How in Worklight application create html link, to open file with default program in device using mimes?

Tags: file, path, ibm-mobilefirst, mime

In simple html, link looks like (this is just an example):

```
<a href="110.111.112.113/path/to/file/file.pdf">File</a>
```

In preview of app, browser by default offers you to download file and then you can open it with program that you want.
How about Android/iOS applications? How I need to construct universal path to file if I have link to it and mime(ex. "application/pdf")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS handles this automagically for you since it has a built-in PDF file (in the case of PDF). Android does not have this ability and so you will need to implement a Cordova plug-in for it, or any other method for displaying PDFs in Android.

Worklight does not handle this for you.
So in short - Cordova plug-ins.

See here: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/adding-native-functionality/

Comment: But if it is not only pdf file, if it is image, text document (word, ...)?

Comment: The same principle. A Cordova plug-in (basically, native code) that will have to handle it.

Comment: I found FileOpener plugin, implemented it (added into config.xml, included in html as script and ...), but now when I try to call it from console: window.plugins.fileOpener.open("path/of/file"); I got error: "cordova is not defined".

Comment: That makes sense. Preview is not a mobile application. Cordova is available only in mobile devices.